# Enviar los datos del form, mediante ajax, y enviar la peticion en formato obj

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario de registro de usuario en el cual el usuario, introduce los datos y cuando pulsa en el botón registrar, estos datos se envían a una función en la cual recojo los datos y los guardo en formato obj, y este a su vez envía la petición al archivo procesar.php, que se encarga de  enviar una consulta a la bbdd, y comprobar si el usuario ya existe, si existe, se le envía al usuario un mensaje de que ya existe y se le redirige al login, y sino existe, se inserta ese usuario.

El problema que yo tengo es que la petición no se esta enviando al procesarusuario.php.

El archivo con el formulario es el siguiente.

```html
        <form id="registerform" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="usuario">Nombre del Usuario</label></td>
              <td> <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre del usuario" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="apellidos">Apellidos del Usuario</label>
              </td>
              <td> <input id="txtApellidos" type="text" name="txtApellidos" placeholder="Apellidos del usuario" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="movil">Móvil del Usuario</label>
              </td>
              <td> <input id="txtMovil" type="number" name="txtMovil" placeholder="Móvil del usuario: Ejemplo 666555444" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="dni">DNI del Usuario</label>
              </td>
              <td> <input id="txtDNI" type="text" name="txtDNI" placeholder="DNI del usuario" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
              </td>
              <td> <input id="txtPassword2" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password2" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <div class="d-flex  label-show">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="show-password2" class="w-25">
                  <label id="labelContrasenia">Mostrar contraseña</label>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <label for="email">Email</label>
              </td>
              <td> <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="email" name="txtEmail" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="rol">Rol a desempeñar</label></td>
              <td>
                <select name="opciones" id="opciones">
                <option value="0">Elige la opcion</option>

                <?php foreach ($datosSelect as $value) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['rol']; ?></option>
                <?php };?>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" title="Registrarse" id="registrarse">Registrarse</button>
        </form>
```

Al hacer clickear en el boton llama a la funcion enviarRegistroFormulario

```js
  //SUBMIT
  $(function() { 
   $("#registrarse").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // evita que el formulario se envíe de forma convencional
    console.log("hola");
    enviarRegistroFormulario(); // llama a la función enviarFormulario()
  }); 
}); 
});

//REGISTER
function enviarRegistroFormulario() {
 // Recoger los datos del formulario

/*  let datosFormulario = $('#registerform').serializeArray(); */
/*  let rol=$('#opciones').val(); */

/*  datosFormulario.push({name: "roles", value:rol}); */

  let formData = {
    nombre:$('#txtNombre').val(),
    apellidos:$('#txtApellidos').val(),
    movil:$('#txtMovil').val(),
    dni:$('#txtDNI').val(),
    password:$('#txtPassword2').val(),
    email:$('#txtEmail').val(),
    rol:$('#opciones').val(),
  };
/*  $(this)
   .serializeArray()
   .map(function (x) {
     formData[x.name] = x.value;
   });
 formData.gender = $("#gender").val(); 
 */
 console.log(formData);

 // Convertir el objeto JSON en una cadena
 let datosJson = formData;


 // Enviar los datos al servidor utilizando una petición AJAX
 $.ajax({
   url: "procesar/procesarusuario.php",
   type: "post",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: formData,
 /*   beforeSend: function() {
    // Mostrar el loader o indicador de carga
  }, */
   success: function (respuesta) {
    console.log("a");
      if (respuesta.existe) {
      // Vaciar los campos del formulario
      $('#nombre').val('');
      $('#apellido').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      // Mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario
      alert('El usuario ya existe en la base de datos');
    } else {
      // Si el usuario no existe, enviar la petición AJAX para insertar los datos
     /*  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insertar-usuario.php',
        data: datosFormulario,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(respuesta) {
          // Los datos se han insertado con éxito en la base de datos
          // Redirigir al usuario a la página de éxito
          window.location.href = 'exito.php';
        },
        error: function() {
          // Se ha producido un error al insertar los datos
          // Mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario */ 
          alert('Se ha producido un error al insertar los datos');
        /* } */
      /* }); */
    } 
   },
   error: function () {
     alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
   },
 });
}
```

En el formData, guardo los valores, como clave->valor para que sea un ojeto luego envio ese objeto al procesarusuario.php, que es donde no se me muestra nada

En el archivo procesarusuario.php llamo a la clase donde tengo la funcion, que comprueba si existe en dato en la bbdd o no

```
<?php
 require("../../config.php");
 require_once(ROOT_PATH2 . 'modelo/usuariosModelo.php');

 $usuariosModelo = new UsuariosModelo();

 $datosFormulario = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 var_dump($datosFormulario);
 // Obtener los valores de los campos del formulario
 $nombress = $datosFormulario->nombre;

 $datosSelect = $usuariosModelo->existeUsuario($nombress);
 echo $datosSelect;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al enviar un objeto FormData a través de AJAX o Fetch, no es necesario configurar el tipo de contenido en **"application/json"** al hacerlo causas conflictos en la solicitud.

Ya que el objeto es analizado por JavaScript y automáticamente lo establece en **"multipart/form-data"**.
Tampoco es necesario decodificar la cadena de matriz asociativa **json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);**
puesto que lo recibirás como un **$_POST** normal

Te recomiendo hacer tu script un poco mas limpio y sin usar **JQuery** :

```js
    registrarse.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = new FormData(registerform);
        let opc = {
            method: 'POST',            
            body: form
        };       
        fetch('procesar/procesarusuario.php',opc)
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
    });
```

Y en **php**

```php
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Espero te sirva de punto de partida,
Saludos